# .htaccess redirect with questionmark

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect certain urls matching a pattern to the site root.

I'm doing:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ABCDE.*$ /
```

But whenever there is a ? in the url the resulting link is whatever is after the url. How can I redirect also urls including questionmarks?

Answer (score 0):

To strip off existing query string you need to use `mod_rewrite` rules. Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ABCDE.*$ /? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Maybe this did the trick but perhaps my problem was more complicated then I thought. Actually it is this url that needs to go to the root:
http://www.domain.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?brand2=20&cat=14&q=loose&brand2=20&cat=14&q=loose

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess file? Do you want to match this **exact query** string?